# Regular Expression help for something inside ()

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to build a regular expression that will have "( )" and anything inside that brackets.

```
\b([a-zA-Z [0-9]])\b
```

its usually text like

```
(not set)
(Content Targeting)
(content targeting)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\([a-zA-Z ]+\)$
```

You need to escape the parenthesis. You also want to allow more than one character inside, so do that with a `+` or `*` (zero or more)

I use [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) to test regular expressions. It has a nice quick reference in the top right. MDN has a more complete reference: [RegExp - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions)

Comment: You should replace `.*` with `[^\)]+`

Comment: the text inside can have spaces also

Comment: what does dot do ? is there any guide where i can learn basics ?

Comment: @HarshaMV dot matches any character. [RegExp - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions)

Comment: Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found [APP\Controller\MetricsController.php, line 51]

Comment: The `^` means start of string, you can take that and the `$` (end of string) out if you dont need em.

Comment: oh God this is driving me crazyy Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: The regex needs to be wrapped in forward slashes... `$pattern = '/regex/';`

Comment: Good site to delve into regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues with your pattern:

```
    \b([a-zA-Z [0-9]])\b
      ^        ^
      |   already in class
 not escaped
```

Already in class can be fixed by removing the square brackets and to escape the round brackets use the `\` character:

```
    \b\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]\)\b
      ^^       ^^^  ^^
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash :(

Comment: Sure, I left the delimiters out there so they don't stand in the way.